# matlab - what is the equivalent of null / None / nil / NULL etc.?

Tags: matlab

In most OO languages, where variables may point to objects, they may also have a null value, which is highly convenient.

In Matlab, I have a function which parses a command, and then returns a cell array, or `false` (which is equal to zero — which is another common pattern) if it fails:

```
function re = parse(s)
    ...
    if (invalid)
        re = false;
        return;
    end
end
```

The problem is that when I check the result, it gives an error:

```
re = parse(s);
if (false == re)
Undefined function 'eq' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
```

I've written a function to check it without an error: `strcmp('logical', class(re)) && false == re`, but that seems to be really slow for use in hot areas of the code, and also inconvenient if I have to add this function to every M file I'm writing.

Using `NaN` is even worse, because besides throwing that error, it also isn't equal to itself.

What's a better alternative for use with this pattern?

Comment: To address one of your points, idiomatic matlab is to use `isnan(A)` to check for nan, rather than `A==NaN` (since as you found out, the latter doesn't work).

Comment: It would be another alternative, but unfortunately e.g. `isnan({})` throws an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `isequal` function to compare any two items without causing that error.  For example:

```
if isequal (re, false)
    %code here
end
```

Answer (score 3):

A good alternative is to use the empty array: `[]` and `isempty(re)` to check. This doesn't throw the error.

Reference: http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/148764

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the function `parse` one solution would be to return two output arguments `[re status] = parse(s)`, where `status` would be logical variable. Set it to true in case of success, and to false otherwise.

Comment: This will always work, even if `[]` was a valid result of `parse(..)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the empty cell array `{}` if it is not a valid result otherwise. Using empty matrices is MATLAB standard (see Evgeni Sergeev's answer), but using an empty cell array instead of an empty numeric array ensures that you'll always end up with the same type of result.

If, on the other hand, the empty cell array `{}` is a valid result of your function, then I'd use an exception to signalize a problem:

```
if invalid
    error('Parse:InvalidArgumentError', 'The input is invalid.');
end
```

Make sure to use an appropriate error ID (first argument to `error`) so that you can catch exactly that exception when you call the function:

```
try:
    result = parse(something);
catch ME
    if strcmp(ME.identifier, 'Parse:InvalidArgumentError')
        fprintf('Ooops\n');
    else
        % Some other error
        ME.rethrow();
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that matlab functions don't return pointers but copies of values.

IMHO the best best approach would be to define your own "pointer" class. Inside you can define an "isNull()" command or even override comparison to produce the behavior you desire.